# Getting XML node using XPath returns null

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I am trying to get a node in a simple XML, but no matter what I try I always get null.

I am guessing that the issue is the namespace.

I am simply trying to get the value of the `ID` element, 331377697.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("E:\\0323.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("cac", "http://xxxxxx Some URL XXXX");
manager.AddNamespace("cbc", "http://xxxxxx Some URL XXXX");

string query = "/StandardBusinessDocument/Invoice/cbc:ID";

XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(query, manager);
```

The XML:

```
<StandardBusinessDocument xmlns="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
      <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
      ...
      </StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
...
</Invoice>
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>1234</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>1234564</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>331377697</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2017-03-23</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listID="ISO4217">NOK</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cac:OrderReference>
        <cbc:ID>146136</cbc:ID>
    </cac:OrderReference>

    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the exact namespaces.

Also you have to specify namespace prefixes for all elements in the XPath.

```cs
manager.AddNamespace("nsDoc", "http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader");
manager.AddNamespace("nsInvoice", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2");
manager.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");

string query = "/nsDoc:StandardBusinessDocument/nsInvoice:Invoice/cbc:ID";
```

It's supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you :-). It works great. But your "nsDoc" and "nsInvoce" could be any name, right? So I guess if namespece is used anywhere in the XML, you need use it everyehere, for xpath to work.

Comment: Yes, it could be any name. As well as `cbc`.